# OpenCV addweighted function gives a unhandled exception after 4th loop

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to blend a small image into multiple areas of a larger image .
Here is my code :

```
for(int i=0;i<m_numKeypoints;i++)
{
    Keypoint kp = m_keyPoints[i];
    kp.scale;
    //cvLine(img, cvPoint(kp.xi, kp.yi), cvPoint(kp.xi, kp.yi), CV_RGB(255,255,255), 3);
    //cvLine(img, cvPoint(kp.xi, kp.yi), cvPoint(kp.xi+10*cos(kp.orien[0]), kp.yi+10*sin((double)kp.orien[0])), CV_RGB(255,255,255), 1);
    // find the points where X and Y is the centre of the rectangle ROI
    ROIa=calculateFirstPoint(kp.xi,kp.yi,rectX,rectY); 
    ROIb=calculateSecondPoint(kp.xi,kp.yi,rectX,rectY);
    if (kp.scale>2 && kp.scale<10)
    {
        ROI=yuv_channels[0](Rect(ROIa,ROIb));
        addWeighted(ROI,0.5,watermark,0.5,0.0,ROI);

    }
    else if (i==m_numKeypoints-1)
    {
        merge(yuv_channels,3,resImg);
        imshow("Result",resImg);
    }
}
```

However when it gets into the IF condition , it gives me a "Unhandled exception at 0x5b78ad7a (msvcp100d.dll) in MySIFT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0." after i=3  . 
I have no idea what is wrong and it would be greatly appreciated if anybody could shed some light into this problem . 
Thank you .

Comment: what's array size of m_keyPoints? and did you try to debug it?

Comment: The array size of m_keyPoints is 68 . The exception occurs when I try to step over from      ROI=yuv_channels[0](Rect(ROIa,ROIb)); to the addWeighted function in the IF condition , when i > 3 .

Comment: yuv_channels stores array of function pointers?

Comment: yuv_channles stores the array of the different components of a multi channel array . 
    Mat image=imread("C:\\picture.png",1);
    split(image,yuv_channels); //split into yuv components

Above shows how i create the yuv_array and from the documentation of OpenCV :

"C++: void split(const Mat& src, Mat* mvbegin)" 

So yuv_channels[0] stores the array for the greyscale component for my input image

Comment: To add on , 
I tried moving the line "ROI=yuv_channels[0](Rect(ROIa,ROIb));" outside of the IF condition and the same exception occurs when I > 3. It's like the code "ROI=yuv_channels[0](Rect(ROIa,ROIb));" can only be executed 3 times before an exception occurs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would print the values of `ROIa` and `ROIb`, most likely for the fourth feature one of these points is outside `yuv_channels[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . I think i may have figured out the problem . The x and y values is in int , but the calculation is done using float values , so during one of the checks in CVassert where ROIa.y + ROIb.y <= 480 it becomes 481 <= 480 instead . Thus causing the exception as mentioned above . 
Many thanks to all that tried to help !